# mysql.service is missing but shows up on list - fails install

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-17.04

I'm on Ubuntu 17.04.

Long story short, after wrestling with MariaDB for a bit, I followed some questionable advice on how to *completely* remove both MySQL and MariaDB from my home server.  Now I'm unable to reinstall `mysql-server`.  I'm getting this error when I try:

```
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
```

So I check for the service with `sudo service --status-all | grep mysql`, and sure enough...

```
[ - ]  mysql
```

Problem is, when I try `sudo service mysql status`, I get

```
Unit mysql.service could not be found.
```

I'd really like to get MySQL installed and working again without doing a clean install!  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The process may have zombied?  You may likely have to reboot and try again.

Comment: I thought so, too.  I restarted a few times.  Also, `ps aux | grep mysql` doesn't show anything.

Answer (score 23):

Looks like I got it.  It doesn't make any sense, but I got it. First, I asked `dpkg` whether any mysql packages were still around:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep mysql
```

Nothing came up, so I checked for MariaDB:

```
sudo dpkg --get-selections | grep maria
```

This showed some packages marked for deinstallation.

```
mariadb-client-10.1                             deinstall
mariadb-common                                  deinstall
mariadb-server-10.1                             deinstall
```

Since `apt` wasn't cooperating, I uninstalled each one with `dpkg -P`.  Once I did that and rebooted, mysql was no longer listed as a service and `mysql-server` installed perfectly.  Hope this saves someone else some time.

Comment: Thanks for posting your discovery!

Comment: thx for your answer ---> "I uninstalled each one with dpkg -P" ---> how do you do that?

Answer (score 3):

The `dpkg -P` answer didn't work for me, but the procedure below did. Summary:

There's some interaction between MariaDB and MySQL that prevents `/etc/init.d/mysql` being removed during an uninstall. This prevents MySQL uninstalling fully, or re-installing. If you manually remove this file, and then repeat the uninstall, things should work. However, it took me a while to reach this conclusion, and the system had changed, so I didn't try this directly. The full procedure that worked for me is below, for `apt`-based systems.

In `/var/lib/dpkg/info` you'll find the relevant packages:

```
# cd /var/lib/dpkg/info
# ll | grep -i mariadb
# ll | grep -i mysql
```

The packages have a set of suffixes, which are `.preinst`, `.prerm`, and so on. If there's a `php8.1-mysql.prerm`, for example, the package can be removed as

```
# dpkg --purge --force-all php8.1-mysql
```

Eventually, you're left with `mysql-server-8.0`, which can't be removed, and gives the error message in the question. This contains:

```
if [ -z "${DPKG_ROOT:-}" ] && [ "$1" = remove ] && [ -x "/etc/init.d/mysql" ] ; then
    invoke-rc.d mysql stop || exit 1
fi
```

The problem is that `/etc/init.d/mysql` wasn't removed by the uninstall. Remove this file manually, and the uninstall will now complete.

You can now install `mysql-server`. This completes, but may not install everything on the first attempt - you'll have to clear the apt cache, or similar - I don't remember the exact details.

Comment: That's correct for /etc/init.d/mysql wasn't removed by the uninstall