# Received Linux "Error: BrokenCount > 0" after trying to fix mysql install?

Tags: mysql, linux, ubuntu

I tried fixing a mysql install after getting error codes. I tried removing then reinstalling. I tried installing mariadb and removing. Then tried again. Eventually something happened and got "Error: BrokenCount > 0". So the package manager is broken. I tried `sudo apt -f install` and I get the following messages in the terminal.

```
user@linux:~$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  galera-3 libconfig-inifiles-perl libdbi-perl libreadline5 socat
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following additional packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-8.0
Suggested packages:
  mailx tinyca
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  mysql-server-8.0
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/1,329 kB of archives.
After this operation, 1,536 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 218690 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../mysql-server-8.0_8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb ...
Failed to stop mysql.service: Unit mysql.service not loaded.
invoke-rc.d: initscript mysql, action "stop" failed.
invoke-rc.d returned 5
There is a MySQL server running, but we failed in our attempts to stop it.
Stop it yourself and try again!
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.26-0
ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb (--unpack):
 new mysql-server-8.0 package pre-installation script subprocess returned error 
exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/mysql-server-8.0_8.0.26-0ubuntu0.20.04.3_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Assistance with this problem would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following two posts to resolve my problem.

[mysql.service is missing but shows up on list - fails install](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494749/mysql-service-is-missing-but-shows-up-on-list-fails-install)

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1012223/0-upgraded-0-newly-installed-0-to-remove-and-0-not-upgraded-1-not-fully-insta

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).